# Rejected - Invalid destination exchange specified

Tags: r, tws

```
exerciseOptions(tws,acc_[[2]][[10]]$contract)
 acc_[[2]][[10]]$contract$exch
[1] "AMEX"
 acc_[[2]][[10]]$contract$primary
[1] "AMEX"
 acc_[[2]][[10]]$contract$primary
[1] "AMEX"
```

When I run the first line in Rstudio a message on my tws appear: `"Rejected - Invalid destination exchange specified"`

You have a solution for this? All answers I found has not solved my problem.

Comment: the first line I mean: "exerciseOptions(tws,acc_[[2]][[10]]$contract)"

Comment: which contract are you trying to reach ? It looks like AMEX is not a valid exchange